# Wordpress download 2 different pdf files based on user login

Tags: php, html, wordpress, authentication, logout

I'd like to create a button in a loop where to get two different pdf files based on user login. If a user is logged out I want that this button becomes with label "Download a sample" and the function allow to download the pdf file sample. Viceversa if a user is logged in the button label is "Download" and the function allow users to download the full pdf file.

Any ideas o how to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Manny

Answer (score 0):

I highly encourage you next time to give us the code you have already tried so users aren't redoing work you've already tried.

Now then... wordpress has a builtin `is_user_logged_in()` function, so you can hook onto that and put it into your page code somewhere for displaying the content.

Example:

```
<?php 
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<button href="pdf-full.pdf" class="pdf-button">Download PDF</button>';
  } else {
    echo '<button href="pdf-sample.pdf" class="pdf-button">Download PDF Sample</button>';
  }
?>
```

Hope this works for you.